# Which C# Socket function sends HTTP/1.1 200 OK to client?

Tags: c#, sockets

I wrote an asynchronous server routine that listens for HTTP POST requests and extracts the data.

It works but the client that sends the requests is complaining about not getting the "200 OK" response when I'm done with the connection.

So I need to know which Socket method(s) returns the acknowledgement. I haven't found such info in the MSDN documentation.

List of Socket methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socket_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: None, really.  The socket library does not know anything about HTTP.  You need to use the Send() methods and construct your own response manually.

Comment: Or use HttpListener, of course.